# Pairwise product between array of vectors and array of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array `A` which I am representing here as `[v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n]`.

I have a 3-d tensor `B` which I am representing here as `[m_1, m_2, m_3, ...n m_n]`.

```
A.type = numpy.ndarray

A.shape = (300, 4)

B.type = numpy.ndarray

B.shape = (300, 4, 2)
```

I want to get the 1D array `C = A*B` such that `C = [u_1, u_2, u_3, ..., u_n]` where `u_i = np.dot(v_i, m_i)`

How can I do this without iterating over `1` to `n` and using `numpy.tensordot()` over `A` and `B`?

Comment: `np.tensordot(A, B, axes=2)` would return `C' = [u1 + u2 + u3 + ... + un]`. However it doesn't seem to be possible to obtain the `C` you want by simply specifying the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) function to do that. that will let you give a letter (index) to each dimension of the arrays you supply as a string and use the einstein sum notation to process. so in you case I'd say something like:

```
np.einsum( "ik,ikl->il", A,B )
```

so in this case i'd name the dimensions of A i,k --> 300,4 and the dimensions of B have to be i,k and something else e.g. l --> 300,4,2 an then with the arrow you specify which dimensions you want to get out. If you don't supply a letter (index) in the notation after the arrow this dimension will be summed over. so had you done "ik,ikl->l" it would have summed over the 300 dimension.

Comment: Yup! That solves it! :D
Thanks so much...I wasn't even aware of the einsum!